# How to write modular Android code

Tags: android, modular

I have 5 activities that each display 10 buttons.  The buttons are shown or hidden based on data out of a database.  Currently, I have the exact same code in all 5 activities.  How do I create a single module that can be included in each activity so that I don't have to replicate the code?

I currently include the same code that is within a loop in each module:

```
if ( i == 1 ) ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1 )).setVisibility( visible ) ;
if ( i == 2 ) ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2 )).setVisibility( visible ) ;
if ( i == 3 ) ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3 )).setVisibility( visible ) ;
if ( i == 4 ) ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4 )).setVisibility( visible ) ;
if ( i == 5 ) ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5 )).setVisibility( visible ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to make the code shorter, you can create an array of ids and use i as an index:

```
int ids[] = { R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3, R.id.btn4,R.id.btn5};

// ....

if (i >= ids.length) {
  // some error
}
else {
    ((Button) findViewById(ids[i] )).setVisibility( visible );
}
```

If the buttons are different from activity to activity, you can create a static method:

```
public static boolean setVisible(int[] ids, int i) {
    if (i >= ids.length) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        ((Button) findViewById(ids[i] )).setVisibility( visible );
        return true;
    }    
}
```

If they are all the same, you can create the array as a static array in the same class as the static method, and pass only the index.

Comment: Wouldn't pulling that method up into a Abstract Base Class and making it virtual be a better idea?  That way it's only in 1 place, and you get the advantage of being able to override it on a case by case basis if you needed an extra button for 1 activity out of 10.

Comment: @Justin Shield - Your comment is not clear, are you talking about C#?

Comment: Sorry virtual ~= overrideable from C# to Java.  What I'm trying to get at is that in all 5 activities you'll be replicating the same int[] structure for each activity.  If that int[] doesn't change between those activities pulling that array into the method and the putting that method into an abstract base class can reduce the amount of duplication in all of the activities.

Comment: @Justin Shield - I will rephrase my answer